# How to prevent view re-rendering inside dynamic layout when route (and therefore dynamic layout) is changed in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vuejs-slots

When I navigate from the page from MainLayout to the page that has CallLayout, Call view is re-rendered.

AppLayout.vue:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { markRaw, shallowRef, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';

const layout = shallowRef();
const route = useRoute();

watch(layout, () => console.log('%c Layout has been changed', 'color: aqua'));

watch(
  () => route.meta?.layout,
  async (metaLayout) => {
    console.log('%c Updating layout', 'color: aqua');
    try {
      const component =
        metaLayout && (await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `./${metaLayout}.vue`));
      layout.value = markRaw(component?.default || DefaultLayout);
    } catch (error) {
      layout.value = markRaw(DefaultLayout);
    }
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <Component :is="layout">
    <slot />
  </Component>
</template>
```

Call.vue:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
console.log('Render Call component');
</script>

<template>
  <p>Call component</p>
</template>
```

I have the following logs:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b9Jp.png)

Comment: looks OK, what is the problem? what metaLayout value at console.log('%c Updating layout', 'color: aqua');?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev The problem is that Call component renders twice whereas I navigate to the call page only once. metaLayout in the console log is CallLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I figured out the cause of the problem. Since I import component asynchronously, watch callback is also asynchronous. However, vue doesn't wait for callback completion and renders layout and the view immediately after callback call. When component is imported, `layout` gets updated and vue re-renders the layout along with the view.

We cannot make vue wait for asynchronous callbacks, but we can disable rendering till layout gets imported by introducing another reactive variable `layoutLoading` and using conditional rendering. Here is fixed version of AppLayout.vue:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { markRaw, ref, shallowRef, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';
import Loading from '@/components/Shared/Loading.vue';

const layout = shallowRef();
const route = useRoute();

const layoutLoading = ref(true);

watch(
  () => route.meta?.layout,
  async (metaLayout) => {
    layoutLoading.value = true;

    try {
      const component =
        metaLayout && (await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `./${metaLayout}.vue`));

      layout.value = markRaw(component?.default || DefaultLayout);
    } catch (error) {
      layout.value = markRaw(DefaultLayout);
    }

    layoutLoading.value = false;
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <Component :is="layout" v-if="!layoutLoading">
    <slot />
  </Component>
  <Loading v-else></Loading>
</template>
```